# Kotlin : Picasso Problem at convert URL to Bitmap

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, bitmap, picasso

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxPRD.png)

at this code have "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should not happen from the main thread." problem

how to solve this

user_URL[i] value is (URL : String)

The code is :

```
    user_URL = maprepo.returnImage()
    latitude = maprepo.returnLatitude()
    longitude = maprepo.returnLongitude()

    for (i in 0 until latitude.size step (1)) {

        var bitmap: Bitmap =Picasso.with(context).load(user_URL[i]).get()

        val makerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        makerOptions
            .position(LatLng(latitude[i], longitude[i]))
            .title("")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))

        googleMap.addMarker(makerOptions)

    }
```

Comment: Please post source code and stack traces as text, not images. In terms of your problem, if you are going to use `get()` to obtain the `Bitmap` directly, you need to do that work on a background thread. Picasso has built-in ways of doing work on background threads for you, but you cannot use `get()` for that.

Comment: I edit my codes

Comment: @CommonsWare Does picasso not do work on background thread by default using `get()`??

Comment: @Praveen: Correct. `get()` is synchronous -- it blocks the current thread to return the result.